# Why the exception is 0x6982 and not 0x6985?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I am sending a DAP block to the SD. That SD doesn't have Mandated DAP Verification Privilege nor DAP Verification Privilege. But is in personalize state.

I have this scenario:

- Install for load an SD to the card without privileges to the ISD.
- Select the SD and authenticate
- Load a DAP Block knowing the SD doesn't have a DAP Verification Privilege.
- Load command throws exception 0x6982.

I have this other scenario:

- Install the SD without privileges to the ISD
- Select the SD and authenticate
- Extradited the SD to itself
- Select the SD and authenticate
- Load a DAP Block to the SD
- Load command throws exception 0x6982

As far I know, 0x6982 exception is SECURITY_STATUS_NOT_SAISFIED and 0x6985 is CONDITIONS_NOT SATISFIED from GlobalPlatform Specifications v2.3.1. Form it could be both.

I have a method called hasAnyDAPPrivileges(SecurityDomain sd) that throws 0x6982 if the SD (as specified in GP Specifications v2.3.1.):

- Is not an SD o ISD or
- Is not in a personalization state and
- Doesn't have Mandated DAP or DAP Verification Privilege

I didn't find anywhere which exception is and why. I'm asking for help if you find it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.